# Django rest framework api end points not accessble after implementing ouath 2 toolkit

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-drf-renderer

My django rest api endpoints were working with the JWT authentication. Later I changed that to Oauth 2 toolkit. All are working fine from postman rest app. But the api doc test endpoints are not working. It shows the following screen.

[image: API endpoint testing screen]

This page still shows even if I am logged in as administrator. Is there any change I need to do in the settings file?

Current settings in settings.py is

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
'SCOPES': {'read': 'Read scope', 'write': 'Write scope', 'groups': 'Access to your groups'}
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",
'DATE_FORMAT' : "%m/%d/%Y",
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
),
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 50,
'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'app_utils.views.exception_handler'
}
```

Comment: Did you change header? If I am not mistaken for OAUTH2 you need to send Authorization header with Bearer <token> value?

Comment: Its regarding the api listing and testing in browser.

Comment: I know but If you have set IsAuthanticated as permisson class you need to auth user with token. If you just want to access endpoint without any header set it won't let you through while you are not authenticated user.